# I am not able to find file uploaded with Dropzone.js

Tags: php, dropzone.js

I am not able to find file, I uploaded, It is not in the folder where it should be. I do not have any idea what should I do. IT says that upload was done correctly and in console is not any error.

```
<form action="upload.php" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

There is PHP

```
<?php

function post_upload()
{
    $input = Input::all();
    $rules = array(
        'file' => 'image|max:3000'
    );

    $validation = Validator::make($input, $rules);

    if ($validation->fails()) {
        return Response::make($validation->errors->first(), 400);
    }

    $file = Input::file('file');

    $extension = File::extension($file['name']);
    $directory = 'uploads/' . sha1(time());
    echo ($directory);

    $filename = sha1(time() . time()) . ".{$extension}";

    $upload_success = Input::upload('file', $directory, $filename);

    if ($upload_success) {
        return Response::json('success', 200);
    } else {
        return Response::json('error', 400);
    }
}

post_upload();

?>
```

Folder has permission to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's wrong with your code but you can try my working solution:

```
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; 
$store_folder = 'uploads';  

if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];                      
    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ).$ds.$store_folder.$ds; 
    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name']; 

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);

}
```

Comment: Great Thanks, Is there also the way how to upload all the paths to one column in mysql database ?